# Load balancing between Linone and EC2 with Nginx

Tags: amazon-ec2, nginx, load-balancing, linode

How to load balance with Nginx between a Linode and an EC2 instance?
I don't want to use subdomains like

```
www1.abc.com
www2.abc.com
```

So there are different IP addresses, but I just want see  **abc.com** from "outside".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per: http://mickeyben.com/blog/2009/12/30/using-nginx-as-a-load-balancer/

You would need once instance of Nginx running somewhere.

Comment: Is kind of funny that the link respond with a nginx error. Do you have a way to fix it?